# Text messages including a .casa TLD link are never delivered to iPhone users?

Tags: iphone, sms

I bought a .casa domain name (whose content is a javascript redirect) with the hopes of sending it over SMS. It is delivered fine to Android devices. But iPhone users never receive the text nor any indication that a message was filtered/blocked.

It's happened multiple times now. Not sending to random people, these are people I'm in the middle of a conversation with. The SMS content would be e.g. "Starts at 6pm at [https://example.casa/"](https://example.casa/%22)

What's going on here any is there any way to get this link delivery to work?

Answer (score 1):

Okay oof. I just found this article: https://www.spotvirtual.com/blog/the-perils-of-an-xyz-domain/ which states that apparently some SMS carriers block links of entire TLDs. They mention .xyz in the article. Apparently also happening here with .casa. According to https://www.spamhaus.org/statistics/tlds/ , .casa is the 6th spammiest TLD, even worse than .xyz.

So it may be the sender or recipient's carrier and not iMessage.

Note to self (quote from article): "Avoid at all costs (or savings) all domains which are priced incredulously cheap."